# Docker container DNS alias available in other containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to set up two Docker containers where both know its own and the others DNS name. If it has to be only in one direction it's easily made with links. But links build a dependency between containers which stop them from starting.

What I want is something like this (docker-compose.yml):

```
version: '3'
services:

  one:
    hostname: one.priv
    links:
      - "two:two.priv"

  two:
    hostname: two.priv
    links:
      - "one:one.priv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in docker-compose v3 creating networks and aliases.

You can define a network, or two (i'll write a more complicated example):

```
networks:
  mynetwork:
  mynetwork2:
```

and then define an alias in each network:

```
services:
  one:
    networks:
      mynetwork1:
        aliases:
         - one
         - one.priv
      mynetwork2:
        aliases:
         - one2
  two:
      mynetwork1:
        aliases:
         - two
         - two.priv
      mynetwork2:
        aliases:
         - two
```